# Android: Write string to file

Tags: android, file, outputstream

i tried to write a string to a specific file but it wont work.
I tried it with this part of code down here but it isn't writing anything in my .txt file

```
private void writeToFile(String data) {
    try {
        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/config/url.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
        outputStreamWriter.write(data);
        outputStreamWriter.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
    } 
}
```

I don't know why this isn't working, it would be great to receive some help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenFileOutput accepts a filename without separators, as written below

[Context | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

So it would be

```
Writer writer = null;
try {
    writer = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("url.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
    writer.write(data);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (writer != null) writer.close();
}
```

For a private directory.
Note that there is no such thing as private mode on an external storage.

It is a bad idea to store configuration files on external storage, because

- The file messes folder structure
- The file will not be deleted with the app nor cleared with data
- The file can be deleted by user or removed if the external storage is removable
- The file can be easily accessed and violated by a user.

So what you probably need is what I've said above, but if you really need to write there, the proper way is listed below

Also I don't like hardcoding separators.
Also, if you need a file on an external storage, proper way of creating a File object is

```
Writer writer = null;
try {
    // get config dir
    final File configDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "config");
    //make sure it's created
    configDir.mkdir();
    // open a stream
    writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(new File(configDir, "url.txt")));
    writer.write(data);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (writer != null) writer.close();
}
```

Comment: You code is right, but block finally is not call in same case

Comment: @SciJoker In what case? *fInally* is always called whenever first line in *try* was was called. The only case when it's not called is a crash.

Comment: Because a finally block will always be called unless you call System.exit() (or the thread crashes).

Comment: Thank you very much Doctoror Drive! This worked for me! I've done this, because on my phone the main folder is the external folder.

Comment: @SciJoker never tried this, but calling System.exit() is a bad idea anyway. Especially in a try block.

Comment: @Einstein you're welcome. Writing to an internal folder should work pretty much okay and is a recommended way.

Comment: You right +1. But are sames developers that not know about it

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
private void writeToFile(String data) {
    try {

        File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/config/");

        if (dir.exists()) {
            // do nothing folder already exists
        } else {
            // make file folder
            dir.mkdirs();
        }

        File statText = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/config/url.txt");
        FileOutputStream is = new FileOutputStream(statText);
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(is);
        Writer w = new BufferedWriter(osw);
        w.write(data);
        w.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
    } 
}
```

Comment: You've forgot to make sure the config dir is created. This can fail. Also you haven't closed the streams.

Comment: After wrote data to file U must close streams connections

Comment: Now everyone should be happy :P

Answer (score 0):

For this case, especially on Android, the way going for bytes is usually faster.

With this, I solved it by setting up a class which is given the responsibility to deal with reading/writing bytes from/to file through stream.

As far as it's knew generally, `string.getBytes((charset == null) ? DEFAULT_CHARSET:charset)` can help us to transfer string you want to bytes you need.

To use FileHelper, run as below: `FileHelper.getInstance().writeStringToFile(FileHelper.getInstance().createInternalFile("dir_name", "file_name.txt", context), "a string going to be written to /dir_name/file_name.txt", null);`

```
public class FileHelper {
private static final String DEFAULT_DIR_NAME = "AmoFromTaiwan";
private static final int DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
private static final Charset DEFAULT_CHARSET = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
private static final int EOF = -1;
private static FileHelper INSTANCE = new FileHelper();

public static FileHelper getInstance() {
    return INSTANCE;
}

private boolean isExternalStorageWritable(Context context) {
    /*
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    return Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state);
    */
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (context.checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return true;
        } else {
            Logger.e("!!! checkSelfPermission() not granted");
            return false;
        }
    } else { //permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon installation
        return true;
    }
}

private boolean isExternalStorageReadable(Context context) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (context.checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return true;
        } else {
            Logger.e("!!! checkSelfPermission() not granted");
            return false;
        }
    } else { //permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon installation
        return true;
    }
}

@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
private String generateFileNameBasedOnTimeStamp() {
    return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_hhmmss").format(new Date()) + ".jpeg";
}

public File createExternalFile(String dir_name, String file_name, Context context) {
    String dir_path;
    String file_path;
    File dir ;
    File file;
    if (!isExternalStorageWritable(context)) {
        Logger.e("!!! external storage not writable");
        return null;
    }
    if (dir_name == null) {
        dir_path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + DEFAULT_DIR_NAME;
    } else {
        dir_path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + dir_name;
    }
    Logger.d("... going to access an external dir:" + dir_path);
    dir = new File(dir_path);
    if (!dir.exists()) {
        Logger.d("... going to mkdirs:" + dir_path);
        if (!dir.mkdirs()) {
            Logger.e("!!! failed to mkdirs");
            return null;
        }
    }
    if (file_name == null) {
        file_path = dir_path + File.separator + generateFileNameBasedOnTimeStamp();
    } else {
        file_path = dir_path + File.separator + file_name;
    }
    Logger.d("... going to return an external dir:" + file_path);
    file = new File(file_path);
    if (file.exists()) {
        Logger.d("... before creating to delete an external dir:" + file.getAbsolutePath());
        if (!file.delete()) {
            Logger.e("!!! failed to delete file");
            return null;
        }
    }
    return file;
}

public File createInternalFile(String dir_name, String file_name, Context context) {
    String dir_path;
    String file_path;
    File dir ;
    File file;
    if (dir_name == null) {
        dir = new ContextWrapper(context).getDir(DEFAULT_DIR_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    } else {
        dir = new ContextWrapper(context).getDir(dir_name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }
    dir_path = dir.getAbsolutePath();
    Logger.d("... going to access an internal dir:" + dir_path);
    if (!dir.exists()) {
        Logger.d("... going to mkdirs:" + dir_path);
        if (!dir.mkdirs()) {
            Logger.e("!!! mkdirs failed");
            return null;
        }
    }
    if (file_name == null) {
        file = new File(dir, generateFileNameBasedOnTimeStamp());
    } else {
        file = new File(dir, file_name);
    }
    file_path = file.getAbsolutePath();
    Logger.d("... going to return an internal dir:" + file_path);
    if (file.exists()) {
        Logger.d("... before creating to delete an external dir:" + file.getAbsolutePath());
        if (!file.delete()) {
            Logger.e("!!! failed to delete file");
            return null;
        }
    }
    return file;
}

public File getExternalFile(String dir_name, String file_name, Context context) {
    String dir_path;
    String file_path;
    File file;
    if (!isExternalStorageWritable(context)) {
        Logger.e("!!! external storage not writable");
        return null;
    }
    if (dir_name == null) {
        dir_path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + DEFAULT_DIR_NAME;
    } else {
        dir_path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + dir_name;
    }
    if (file_name == null) {
        file_path = dir_path;
    } else {
        file_path = dir_path + File.separator + file_name;
    }
    Logger.d("... going to return an external file:" + file_path);
    file = new File(file_path);
    if (file.exists()) {
        Logger.d("... file exists:" + file.getAbsolutePath());
    } else {
        Logger.e("!!! file does't exist:" + file.getAbsolutePath());
    }
    return file;
}

public File getInternalFile(String dir_name, String file_name, Context context) {
    String file_path;
    File dir ;
    File file;
    if (dir_name == null) {
        dir = new ContextWrapper(context).getDir(DEFAULT_DIR_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    } else {
        dir = new ContextWrapper(context).getDir(dir_name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }
    if (file_name == null) {
        file = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath());
    } else {
        file = new File(dir, file_name);
    }
    file_path = file.getAbsolutePath();
    Logger.d("... going to return an internal dir:" + file_path);
    if (file.exists()) {
        Logger.d("... file exists:" + file.getAbsolutePath());
    } else {
        Logger.e("!!! file does't exist:" + file.getAbsolutePath());
    }
    return file;
}

private byte[] readBytesFromFile(File file) {
    Logger.d(">>> path:" + file.getAbsolutePath());
    FileInputStream fis;
    long file_length;
    byte[] buffer;
    int offset = 0;
    int next = 0;
    if (!file.exists()) {
        Logger.e("!!! file doesn't exists");
        return null;
    }
    if (file.length() > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
        Logger.e("!!! file length is out of max of int");
        return null;
    } else {
        file_length = file.length();
    }
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        //buffer = new byte[(int) file_length];
        buffer = new byte[(int) file.length()];
        long time_start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while (true) {
            Logger.d("... now next:" + next + " and offset:" + offset);
            if (System.currentTimeMillis() - time_start > 1000) {
                Logger.e("!!! left due to time out");
                break;
            }
            next = fis.read(buffer, offset, (buffer.length-offset));
            if (next < 0 || offset >= buffer.length) {
                Logger.d("... completed to read");
                break;
            }
            offset += next;
        }
        //if (offset < buffer.length) {
        if (offset < (int) file_length) {
            Logger.e("!!! not complete to read");
            return null;
        }
        fis.close();
        return buffer;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Logger.e("!!! IOException");
        return null;
    }
}

public byte[] readBytesFromFile(File file, boolean is_fis_fos_only) {
    if (file == null) return null;
    if (is_fis_fos_only) {
        return readBytesFromFile(file);
    }
    Logger.d(">>> path:" + file.getAbsolutePath());
    FileInputStream fis;
    BufferedInputStream bis;
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos;
    byte[] buf = new byte[(int) file.length()];
    int num_read;
    if (!file.exists()) {
        Logger.e("!!! file doesn't exists");
        return null;
    }
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
        bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        long time_start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while (true) {
            if (System.currentTimeMillis() - time_start > 1000) {
                Logger.e("!!! left due to time out");
                break;
            }
            num_read = bis.read(buf, 0, buf.length); //1024 bytes per call
            if (num_read < 0) break;
            bos.write(buf, 0, num_read);
        }
        buf = bos.toByteArray();
        fis.close();
        bis.close();
        bos.close();
        return buf;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Logger.e("!!! FileNotFoundException");
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Logger.e("!!! IOException");
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * streams (InputStream and OutputStream) transfer binary data
 * if to write a string to a stream, must first convert it to bytes, or in other words encode it
 */
public boolean writeStringToFile(File file, String string, Charset charset) {
    if (file == null) return false;
    if (string == null) return false;
    return writeBytesToFile(file, string.getBytes((charset == null) ? DEFAULT_CHARSET:charset));
}

public boolean writeBytesToFile(File file, byte[] data) {
    if (file == null) return false;
    if (data == null) return false;
    FileOutputStream fos;
    BufferedOutputStream bos;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
        bos.write(data, 0, data.length);
        bos.flush();
        bos.close();
        fos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Logger.e("!!! IOException");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

/**
 * io blocks until some input/output is available.
 */
public boolean copy(File source, File destination) {
    if (source == null || destination == null) return false;
    Logger.d(">>> source:" + source.getAbsolutePath() + ", destination:" + destination.getAbsolutePath());
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(source);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(destination);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[(int) source.length()];
        int len;
        while (EOF != (len = fis.read(buffer))) {
            fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
        if (true) { //debug
            byte[] copies = readBytesFromFile(destination);
            if (copies != null) {
                int copy_len = copies.length;
                Logger.d("... stream read and write done for " + copy_len + " bytes");
            }
        }
        return destination.length() != 0;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}

public void list(final String path, final String end, final List<File> files) {
    Logger.d(">>> path:" + path + ", end:" + end);
    File file = new File(path);
    if (file.isDirectory()) {
        for (File child : file.listFiles()){
            list(child.getAbsolutePath(), end, files);
        }
    } else if (file.isFile()) {
        if (end.equals("")) {
            files.add(file);
        } else {
            if (file.getName().endsWith(end)) files.add(file);
        }
    }
}

public String[] splitFileName(File file, String split) {
    String path;
    String ext;
    int lastIndexOfSplit = file.getAbsolutePath().lastIndexOf(split);
    if (lastIndexOfSplit < 0) {
        path = file.getAbsolutePath();
        ext = "";
    } else {
        path = file.getAbsolutePath().substring(0, lastIndexOfSplit);
        ext = file.getAbsolutePath().substring(lastIndexOfSplit);
    }
    return new String[] {path, ext};
}

public File rename(File old_file, String new_name) {
    if (old_file == null || new_name == null) return null;
    Logger.d(">>> old file path:" + old_file.getAbsolutePath() + ", new file name:" + new_name);
    File new_file = new File(old_file, new_name);
    if (!old_file.equals(new_file)) {
        if (new_file.exists()) { //if find out previous file/dir at new path name exists
            if (new_file.delete()) {
                Logger.d("... succeeded to delete previous file at new abstract path name:" + new_file.getAbsolutePath());
            } else {
                Logger.e("!!! failed to delete previous file at new abstract path name");
                return null;
            }
        }
        if (old_file.renameTo(new_file)) {
            Logger.d("... succeeded to rename old file to new abstract path name:" + new_file.getAbsolutePath());
        } else {
            Logger.e("!!! failed to rename old file to new abstract path name");
        }
    } else {
        Logger.d("... new and old file have the equal abstract path name:" + new_file.getAbsolutePath());
    }
    return new_file;
}

public boolean remove(final String path, final String end) {
    Logger.d(">>> path:" + path + ", end:" + end);
    File file = new File(path);
    boolean result = false;
    if (file.isDirectory()) {
        for (File child : file.listFiles()){
            result = remove(child.getAbsolutePath(), end);
        }
    } else if (file.isFile()) {
        if (end.equals("")) {
            result = file.delete();
        } else {
            if (file.getName().endsWith(end)) result = file.delete();
        }
    } else {
        Logger.e("!!! child is not file or directory");
    }
    return result;
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
public byte[] readNIOBytesFromFile(String path) throws IOException {
    Logger.d(">>> path:" + path);
    if (!Files.exists(Paths.get(path), LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS)) {
        Logger.e("!!! file doesn't exists");
        return null;
    } else {
        return Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
    }
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
public File writeNIOBytesToFile(String dir, String name, byte[] data) {
    Logger.d(">>> dir:" + dir + ", name:" + name);
    Path path_dir;
    Path path_file;
    try {
        if (!Files.exists(Paths.get(dir), LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS)) {
            Logger.d("... make a dir");
            path_dir = Files.createDirectories(Paths.get(dir));
            if (path_dir == null) {
                Logger.e("!!! failed to make a dir");
                return null;
            }
        }
        path_file = Files.write(Paths.get(name), data);
        return path_file.toFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Logger.e("!!! IOException");
        return null;
    }
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
public void listNIO(final String dir, final String end, final List<File> files) throws IOException {
    Logger.d(">>> dir:" + dir + ", end:" + end);
    Files.walkFileTree(Paths.get(dir), new FileVisitor<Path>() {
        @Override
        public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs) {
            Logger.d("... file:" + dir.getFileName());
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }

        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) {
            Logger.d("... file:" + file.getFileName());
            if (end.equals("")) {
                files.add(file.toFile());
            } else {
                if (file.endsWith(end)) files.add(file.toFile());
            }
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }

        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed(Path file, IOException exc) {
            Logger.d("... file:" + file.getFileName());
            if (end.equals("")) {
                files.add(file.toFile());
            } else {
                if (file.endsWith(end)) files.add(file.toFile());
            }
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }

        @Override
        public FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory(Path dir, IOException exc) {
            Logger.d("... file:" + dir.getFileName());
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }
    });
}

/**
 * recursion
 */
private int factorial (int x) {
    if (x > 1) return (x*(factorial(x-1)));
    else if (x == 1) return x;
    else return 0;
}
```

}